# How to add backslash and double quote to a string in bash

Tags: string, bash

I need to create a string in Bash with `\"` in the string.

Specifically, I need to create a string like this:

`string="{\"Name\":\"execute_recipes\", \"Args\":{\"recipes\":[$LIST_OF_RECIPES]}}"`

So when I do echo $string, I have to receive:

`{\"Name\":\"execute_recipes\", \"Args\":{\"recipes\":[$LIST_OF_RECIPES]}}`

Comment: Please update the question to include end-to-end context. What you're asking is not useful or helpful in generating JSON. The fact that you can run e.g. `curl -d "{\"Foo\": \"bar\"}" ...` does NOT mean that you should try to generate data with backslashes because that's not how quoting works.

Comment: This sounds a little like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes around should do the trick. Single quotes don't interpolate special characters.

`string='{\"Name\":\"execute_recipes\", \"Args\":{\"recipes\":[$LIST_OF_RECIPES]}}'`